# how to run java file using javascript and batchscript

Tags: java, javascript, batch-file

i want to run java file using javascript. therefore took the help of batch file. when tried following code it is giving, page cannot be displayed... can you please help as early as possible...

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function compression(str)
{
try{
alert("welcum");
  WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
  WshShell.Run (str,1,true);}
catch(e)
{
document.write("erro has occured ");
}
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<a href="compression('explorer file:///C:\\Documents and 

Settings\\test.bat')">batch File</a>
</body>
</html>

--------test.bat file------
@echo off
cls
javac *.java
java LzwTut
pause
```

Comment: Cant u use java applets which are build already, as there isnt seem that u r passing any new parameters to the class and compiling it.

Comment: the entire gui has been made in javascript and html. the files will be selected at the run time and those are passed as arguments to java file LzwTut. for the time being i passed the value in lzwTut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try the following

```
<a href="compression('file://c:/test.bat');">Batch File</a>
```

Also can you try exec insted of run in the compression function?

Comment: <a href="compression('file://c:/test.bat');">Batch File</a> is not working.

Comment: okay .. can you do one thing just keep your .bat file in C: and try WSHShell.Run (""c:\test.bat"") . Notice the double quote. And keep it in C: so that space in directory path does not cause any issue

Comment: Also Can you try using notepad exe. some thing like <font onClick="compression('file://c:/winnt/notepad.exe');" style="cursor: hand;"><u>Notepad</u></font>. Just replace the path of your notepad.exe

Comment: notepad.exe is working. but for test.bat it gives object error

Comment: thanks alot that href worked. i din specify the path where ma file was saved.